# How to install SSL on DigitalOcean Docker Droplet without domain name?

Tags: docker, ssl, certificate, digital-ocean, droplet

I have a running docker droplet on DigitalOcean but this droplet running on http and I want to run it on https.

I don't want to purchase any domain name. Actually I don't need a domain name, ip address is enough.

Certbot and Letsencrypt are not allowing creating SSL certificate on bare IP address.

Is there any solution for this problem?

How can I do that?

Thank you for your collaborations.

Answer (score 0):

Use openssl for generating the certificates and make the docker daemon trust those certificates.

Comment: How do I make docker to trust certificates? Can you provide an example or related documentation?